# Preloading UIViewController Failing--Transition still Slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller, and one of the views in my navigation controller has a date picker.  The date picker transition is a little slow so I wanted to preload that view.  So to do that in my navigation controller’s viewDidload I instantiate the date picker view with:

```
datePickerViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“datePickerView"];
[datePickerViewController view]
```

I have verified that datePickerViewController's viewDidLoad is being called.  Then when I want to push the datePickerView:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:datePickerViewController animated:YES];
```

But this does not improve the transition speed. What's more is that if I push it, go back, then forward again--the transition is fast, which leads me to believe I'm not preloading the view correctly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you use Instruments to see what's taking the time? If not, I highly recommend trying it first.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the `view` property will only create the view and call `loadView` and `viewDidLoad`. It will however not call `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` and it will not "render" the view. But other than calling the `view` property there is no simple solution preload "more". If its still slow, you should profile your app in Instruments and figure out why its so slow.